# Angular 2 "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am working on an app, which previously worked. I am now trying to add some routing, so have created an app.component file and changed a few parameters, but now I just get a blank screen and this error in the console...

```
Error: ReferenceError: require is not defined
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/client/dev/main.js:2:17)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/client/dev/main.js:6:3)
        at $ (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js:4:8740)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/client/dev/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/client/dev/main.js
```

[image]
My Main.JS file is:

```
"use strict";
var browser_1 = require('angular2/platform/browser');
var app_component_1 = require('./app.component');
browser_1.bootstrap(app_component_1.AppComponent);
```

This is Generated from `main.ts`:

```
import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Whats's wrong with this?

## Update:

Thanks Eric for your suggestion about using the system module in tsconfig.json, but if I do it, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\Gen-App\server\server.js:2
System.register(['express', 'os', 'http', './config/routes.conf', './config/db.conf', './config/passport', './routes/index'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
^

ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\Gen-App\server\server.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\Gen-App\index.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

NB: my server.js code is [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Gen-App/blob/master/server/server.ts)

Comment: Check your tsconfig.json file, see the "module" property, if it is "commonjs", change it to "system" and recompile the files.

Comment: I was also frustrated with this. In addition to what @Eric says, I had to upgrade tsc to latest to use the module 'system'.

Comment: @EricMartinez Thanks, that seems to have worked, but it has now broken my previously working server side code, which is now throwing this error: `ReferenceError: System is not defined`, full details will be added to the question

Comment: Browsers don't have `require` like Node does. You'll need to compile your modules using something like Browserify or Webpack.

Comment: @MikeC Apologies if I have misunderstood you, but server.js is server side code which should run on node?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Yes but it's your client side code (at `http://localhost:3000/client/dev/main.js`) that's throwing the error. The client doesn't have `require`, that's a Node.js thing. Browserify/Webpack/whatever will bundle all of the `require`d things together then introduce it's own `require` function to provide a reference to it. But without doing some kind of pre-bundling or setting up your system to work using System.js, you won't be able to `require` modules on the client.

Comment: @MikeC Ahh, I see thanks. I have fixed that by using the system tsconfig module, but it has thrown up some new errors ( see edit) so I am either looking for a different fix, or to understand why I am now getting the system not defined error

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards That's because you need to be running [System.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) on the client. Using the System tsconfig module just makes sure that the compiled TypeScript code is capable of utilizing System.js.

Comment: @MikeC Not sure why my code wouldn't be working, I think it follows all the guidelines on the SystemJS repo, [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Gen-App/blob/master/client/dev/index.html) is the project.

Comment: Could you add the content of your HTML file? Thanks!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier if you click the link in my comment above there is the full code, including html, or follow the link in the question

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards: Got it! The problem is that you use typescript for both server and client sides in the same project. The client uses systemjs and the server commonjs...

Answer (score 0):

You say you added some routing and now it's not working.  Your `index.html` file needs to include the `router.dev.js` file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```